# How much memory uses an array with one high-index element?

Tags: arrays, memory, raku

Would running this code occupy about 4_000_000 bytes of memory?

```
my uint32 @array;
@array[1_000_000] = 1;
```

Comment: if you want any guarantees, you need to shape your array, eg `my uint32 @array[1_000_001]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you assign element `1_000_000` and each element is 4 bytes, that would be 4_000_004 bytes of memory.  So strictly speaking, the answer is "No"  :-)

But less pedantically: native arrays are guaranteed to be laid out consecutively in memory, so such an assignment would at least allocate a single block of 4 x 1_000_001 = 4_000_004 bytes of memory.  As Christoph stated in his comment, if you want to make sure it is all it will ever allocate, you need to make it a shaped native array.  You will get upper bounds checks as a bonus as well.